# Is the `JS engine` on `IOS` or `MaxOS's` Chrome browser `V8`?Or `JavaScriptCode`?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, v8, javascriptcore

Is the JS engine on IOS or MaxOS's Chrome browser `V8`?Or `JavaScriptCode`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On MacOS, Chrome uses Blink and V8. On iOS, per Apple's policies, Chrome has to use WebKit and JavaScriptCore.

Comment: MacOS and IOS are not the same. Where can I see it, do you have a link?

Comment: Of course they're not the same, see my answer. What do you want to see? Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#iOS help?

Comment: OK, I'll go and see